# How do I create this data structure of unsigined ints?

Tags: java, data-structures, arrays, unsigned-integer

```
 |    0      |    1     |     2      |     3      |
 |------------------------------------------------|
 |    Header Version    |       Message Type      |
 |------------------------------------------------|
 |               Message Length                   |
 |------------------------------------------------|

 |    0      |    1     |     2      |     3      |
 |------------------------------------------------|
 |00000000   | 00000001 |00000000    |00000000    |
 |------------------------------------------------|
 |  0000000000000000000000000000000               |
 |------------------------------------------------|
```

1. Header Version - Unsigned 16 bits - Value is always 1
2. Message Type - Unsigned 16 bits
3. Message Length - Unsigned 32 bits

This is a class I wrote to mimic this data structure.  My concern is converting to unsigned ints. I want to send this packet via SSL. Not too sure if this is correct.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public abstract class Message {

    protected static final short        NULL_MESSAGE_TYPE = 0;
    protected short _headerVersion;
    protected short _messageType;
    protected int   _messageLength;

    protected Message (short headerVersion, short messageType, int messageLength) {

        _headerVersion = headerVersion;
        _messageType = messageType;
        _messageLength = messageLength;

    }


    public short getHeaderVersion() {
        return _headerVersion;
    }

    public short getMessageType() {
        return _messageType;
    }

    public int getMessageLength() {
        return _messageLength;
    }

    protected static short getHeaderVersion(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        return getUnsignedInt16(bytes, 0, 1);
    }

    protected static short getMessageType(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        return getUnsignedInt16(bytes, 2, 3);
    }

    protected static int getMessageLength(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        return getUnsignedInt32(bytes, 4, 7);
    }



    protected static short getUnsignedInt16(byte[] bytes, int beginPosition, int endPosition) throws Exception {


        short value = 0;
        byte shiftValue = 8;

        if (endPosition - beginPosition > 1) 
            throw new Exception("Invalid beginPosition and endPosition");

        for(int position = beginPosition; position <= endPosition; position++) {
            value += unsignedByteToShort(bytes[position]) << shiftValue;

            shiftValue -= 8;
        }

        return value;
    }

    protected static int getUnsignedInt32(byte[] bytes, int beginPosition, int endPosition) throws Exception {

        int value = 0;
        byte shiftValue = 24;

        if ( endPosition - beginPosition > 3)
            throw new Exception("Invalid beginPosition and endPosition");

        for(int position = beginPosition; position <= endPosition; position++) {
            value += unsignedByteToInt( bytes[position] ) << shiftValue;

            shiftValue -= 8;
        }

        return value;

    }



    // Get an unsigned byte to a short
    protected static short unsignedByteToShort(byte b) {

        return (short) (b & 0xFF);
    }


    //Get an unsigned byte to an int
    protected static int unsignedByteToInt(byte b) {

        return (int) (b & 0xFF);
    }




    public static MessageTypes getType(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {

        short headerVersion = getHeaderVersion(bytes);
        short messageType = getMessageType(bytes);

        if (headerVersion != 1)
            throw new Exception("Unsupported Version");

        if(messageType == NULL_MESSAGE_TYPE) {
            return MessageTypes.NULL_MESSAGE_TYPE;
        } else {
            return MessageTypes.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    public abstract byte[] getBytes();

}
```

Derived class:

```
public class NullMessage extends Message {

    public NullMessage() {

        super((short) 1, NULL_MESSAGE_TYPE, 0);  //Using a short for 16 bits unsigned byte
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[8];


        // HEADER VERSION
        bytes[0] = (byte) (_headerVersion >>> 8);  //Shifts a zero to the leftmost position
        bytes[1] = (byte) _headerVersion;

        //MESSAGE TYPE
        bytes[2] = (byte)(_messageType >>> 8);
        bytes[3] = (byte) _messageType;

        //MESSAGE LENGTH
        bytes[4] = (byte)(_messageLength >>> 24);
        bytes[5] = (byte)(_messageLength >>> 16);
        bytes[6] = (byte)(_messageLength >>> 8);
        bytes[7] = (byte)_messageLength;

        return bytes;

    }
}
```

Test is Below

```
public class Client {

    private static String ip = 1.2.3.4";
    private static int DEFAULT_PORT= 8888;


    private static File keyStore = new File(
            "\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\bin\\truststore.jks");

    //this is the password for the keystore
    private static String keyStorePassword = "password";

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() throws IOException,
            GeneralSecurityException {
        // Call getTrustManagers to get suitable trust managers
        TrustManager[] tms = getTrustManagers();

        // Call getKeyManagers to get suitable key managers
        KeyManager[] kms = getKeyManagers();

        // Now construct a SSLContext using these KeyManagers. We
        // specify a null TrustManager and SecureRandom, indicating that the
        // defaults should be used.
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        context.init(kms, tms, null);

        // Finally, we get a SocketFactory, and pass it to SimpleSSLClient.
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = context.getSocketFactory();
        return ssf;
    }

    private static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers() throws IOException,
            GeneralSecurityException {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }
        } };
        return trustAllCerts;
        }

    private static KeyManager[] getKeyManagers() throws IOException,
            GeneralSecurityException {
        // First, get the default KeyManagerFactory.
        String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        KeyManagerFactory kmFact = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);

        // Next, set up the KeyStore to use. We need to load the file into
        // a KeyStore instance.
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keyStore);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        ks.load(fis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        fis.close();

        // Now we initialize the TrustManagerFactory with this KeyStore
        kmFact.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        // And now get the TrustManagers
        KeyManager[] kms = kmFact.getKeyManagers();
        return kms;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory();

            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(
                    ip, DEFAULT_PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(99999999);

            System.out.println("Connecting to "
                    + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() + " : "
                    + socket.getPort());
            System.out.println("Is Connected? " + socket.isConnected());
            socket.startHandshake();

            System.out.println("We Made it!!");


            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

            //RequestMessage requestMessage = new RequestMessage((int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 100), (short)1);
            NullMessage nullMessage = new NullMessage();
            byte[] bytes = nullMessage.getBytes();

            dos.writeInt(bytes.length);

            if(bytes.length > 0) {
                dos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }

            socket.close();
```

Comment: Is there a test for this code? That is the best way to tell if it is correct.

Comment: I'd recommend using a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) instead. It has very convenient methods for adding short, long, etc.

Comment: I'm new to JAVA can you explain.  I should use ByteBuffer in the test driver?

Comment: Are you saying use ByteBuffer instead of ByteArray??  Please explain, an example would be good.

Comment: Yes, instead of a byte array. You really should add some additional information to your question if you want better answers: the `Message` class, for example. Also, whether those 16 and 32 bit elements are big-endian or little-endian, which is very important in such data transfer protocols.

Comment: I included the Message class.  This is big endian format.

Comment: This is big endian format.  Message class is included

Comment: it's in network byte order

Comment: Should I wrap my array in a ByteBuffer?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to find out if your code is correct or not. You should test it yourself first and, if you find a specific issue, we'd be happy to help you with that.